# Image downloader from a website which follows the thumbnail and bulk downloads full images

Tags: download-manager

If I need to use some particular browser, or install some freeware app, or run some freely available script (or whatever I cannot think of) I am okay with that.

(For example, I want to download the full size images [on this page](https://www.facebook.com/pg/quranicvisualmiracles/photos/).)

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd recommend [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or one of its many GUIs for crawling the page directly to get the links, but not knowing the precise nature of your system or the page in question, there are situations where there's nothing to crawl.

I've had success in this line of things with [FlashGot](https://flashgot.net/). It's a Firefox extension designed to prep lists of downloads for the old FlashGet download manager, but you can use it to build gallery pages for bulk downloading by working out the format of the image URLs and putting them together into a fake page that can then be scraped for images. It's a bit of work, but the help is there (you'd be looking for the Build Gallery option in that case)

Comment: That should still work, but the problem is the Facebook API, and I don't know enough about that to be confident in this answer being useful to you in that case, largely because it changes so much